# Using a VBA Try/Except Equivalent for If/Else

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to run through some spreadsheet range and use a try/except in order to build an if/else statement.  The reason I am doing this is because IsNumeric() is not working for me so I am trying to do something like this (try except formatting from python)

```
Dim Temp as Integer
Dim Myrange as Range
Dim Myrow as Range
Set Myrange = Range("A1","A1000")
For Each Myrow in Myrange.Row
  If IsEmpty(Range("A" & Myrow.Row)) Then  
    Exit For 'To escape the loop at the end of the filled cells
  Else
    Try:
      Temp = (Myrow.Value() - 0) 'This causes a #VALUE! error when the Myrow.Value is not a number.
    Except:
        Range("B" & Myrow.Row).Value = Temp 'this sets the value of the rightmost cell to whatever current value of Temp is.
```

I have also tried some other error catching but can't seem to get it in VBA.

```
For Each Myrow In Myrange.Rows
       If IsEmpty(Range("A" & Myrow.Row)) Then
         Exit For
       Else
           On Error Resume Next
           Temp = Myrow.Value() - 0
           If Err.Number = 0 Then
               Range("A" & Myrow.Row).Value = ""
           ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
               Range("B" & Myrow.Row) = Temp
           End If
       End If
   Next Myrow
```

I am really just looking to run down the list, see the first number, set value of B0:Bn1 = Temp, when An is hit (new number), The value of Temp changes to temp2 and then cells Bn1+1 -> Bn2-1 is temp2 until a new number is found etc.

in the worksheet I can do it fine with dragging down formula =(A1-0) to see the error message for those that are not numeric but for some reason I can't code it.

---

Solved this using advice of @MathieuGuindon by using variant type and testing isnumeric on that.  Solution code:

```
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim Myrow As Range
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim NextTemp As Variant

    Set Myrange = Selection
    For Each Myrow In Myrange.Rows
        NextTemp = Range("A" & Myrow.Row).Value
        If IsEmpty(Range("A" & Myrow.Row)) Then
          Exit For
        ElseIf IsNumeric(NextTemp) Then
            Temp = NextTemp
            Range("A" & Myrow.Row).Value = ""
        Else
            Range("B" & Myrow.Row).Value = Temp
                End If
    Next Myrow
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to be doing `Myrow.Value() - 0`?

Comment: The best error handling is no error handling - if assigning `Temp` to `MyRow.Value` throws a *type mismatch*, read `MyRow.Value` into a `Variant` and determine whether `IsNumeric(MyRow.Value)` before trying to coerce it into an `Integer`; then you don't need to worry about error handling.

Comment: Also `On Error Resume Next` should be paired with an `On Error GoTo 0` statement that restores error handling - without it OERN is suppressing all errors in the procedure scope.

Comment: What error you get trying to use `IsNumeric(Myrow.Value)` ?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I was going to ask you for more detail on "The best error handling is no error handling", and then I found you already have a [blog post](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/09/pattern-tryparse/) covering it. Helpful for better understanding of that topic.

Comment: In the `for` the range is only `Myrange` and not `Myrange.Row` and need change `Value()` to only  `Value`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I just read your blog that Robert linked and it's very helpful. I plan to implement that in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I followed your advice and it nailed it!  Not sure how to mark it as answered since this was posted as a comment vs answer.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as accepted - SJR's answer appears to be building on my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of simplification, and picking up on Mathieu's comments, try this. Not sure what you're doing though so may no be quite right.

```
Sub x()

Dim Temp As Variant
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Myrow As Range

Set Myrange = Range("A1", "A1000")

For Each Myrow In Myrange
    If Not IsEmpty(Myrow) Then
        Temp = Myrow.Value - 0
            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
               Myrow.Value = vbNullString
            Else
                Myrow.Offset(, 1).Value = Temp
            End If
    End If
Next Myrow

End Sub
```

Comment: This was essentially what I did, thank you.  not sure how I can post my code.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. However you can post your own code as an answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a dedicated error handler at the end of your sub, and check the error code (13 for Type Mismatch):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub EnumerateValues()
    On Error GoTo err_handle

    Dim Temp As Integer
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim Myrow As Range
    Dim myNumber As Double ' Int? Long?

    Set Myrange = Range("A1", "A1000")

    For Each Myrow In Myrange.Rows
        If IsEmpty(Range("A" & Myrow.Row)) Then
            Exit For ' to escape loop at end of filled cells
        Else
            myNumber = CDbl(Myrow.Value())
            Debug.Print myNumber
        End If
' use label, since VBA doesn't support Continue in loop.
loop_continue:
    Next Myrow

exit_me:
    Exit Sub

err_handle:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 13 ' Type Mismatch
            GoTo loop_continue
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, Err.Number
            GoTo exit_me
    End Select
End Sub
```

This way, if we encounter a value for which `CDbl` (or the equivalent function) fails, we just continue on to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

While the first example contains `Try:` and `Except:` as labels, they provide no error control. Try/Except are [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) error control methods, not [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

It's unclear whether you might have text that looks like numbers in column A. If the `Temp = (Myrow.Value() - 0)` is only meant to determine whether the value in column A is a number and not used as a conversion then SpecialCells can quickly find the numbers in column A.

```
dim rng as range

on error resume next
'locate typed numbers in column A
set rng = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
on error goto 0

If not rng is nothing then
    rng = vbNullString
End If

on error resume next
'locate text values in column A
set rng = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
on error goto 0

If not rng is nothing then
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng.Value
End If
```

You can also use `xlCellTypeFormulas` to return numbers or text returned by formulas.